# Is ValidatableBindableBase not implemented in Prism.Wpf? why?

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-6

Trying to incorporate `ValidatableBindableBase` for easy validation implementation, I've noticed that it's not available in `Prism.Wpf`.

It is available in `Prism.Windows` (Windows 10 UWP) however...

So could I have missed it (where is it then)?

Or is it really not implemented in `WPF` (then why)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation in Prism.Wpf is done by implementing `IDataErrorInfo` or `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interfaces. An example:

```
public abstract class DomainObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private ErrorsContainer<ValidationResult> errorsContainer =
                    new ErrorsContainer<ValidationResult>(
                       pn => this.RaiseErrorsChanged( pn ) );

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return this.ErrorsContainer.HasErrors; }
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors( string propertyName )
    {
        return this.errorsContainer.GetErrors( propertyName );
    }

    protected void RaiseErrorsChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        var handler = this.ErrorsChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName) );
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

This is also explained in the [documentation](http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/05-Implementing-MVVM/#data-validation-and-error-reporting) of Prism.

So why doesn't UWP work that way? Because on UWP you don't have access to those interfaces and thus there was a need for `ValidatableBindableBase` and `BindableValidator` classes. If for some reason, you like this approach, nothing prevents you from taking the UWP classes and bring them to your WPF solution, all the code is [open source](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Validation).

Comment: BindableValidator has
var resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView(mapId);
What would be the replacement for this?

Comment: I use annotation, is it slower than `IDataErrorInfo`/`INotifyDataErrorInfo`? since annotation uses reflection